# Is there a way to add $ to each integer in my printed list?

Tags: kotlin

I found a way to remove the brackets from the list by using replace, however I can't figure out how format it with a $dollar sign for each Integer. Thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.*
```

fun main(){

```
val quarterlySales = mutableListOf<Int>()
println("Please enter your quarterly sales: ")

try {
    while (quarterlySales.count() < 4) {
        quarterlySales.add(readLine()!!.toInt())
    }
    println("Total sales: $${sumSales(quarterlySales)}")
}catch (e: InputMismatchException){
    println("All sales numbers should be numeric.")
}
```

}

fun sumSales(numbers: List): Int {

```
println("Quarterly sales: ${numbers.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","")}")
return numbers.sum()
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    println(list.joinToString { "\$$it" }) // $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
}
```

[joinToString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html)